# Obtaining the point at a certain percentage along a line segment

Tags: c#, geometry, line

I have a method that returns the mid point of a line segment as defined by two points;

```
public static PointF GetMidPoint(PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    return new PointF((p1.X + p2.X) / 2, (p1.Y + p2.Y) / 2);
}
```

Which works exactly as expected.

However, I now need to find an arbitrary percentage along the segment (say, 35%), which in principle should(?) be as easy as;

```
public static PointF GetArbitaryPoint(PointF p1, PointF p2, double percentage)
{
    return new PointF((p1.X + p2.X) / percentage, (p1.Y + p2.Y) / percentage);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case, I think it's a c# issue - as soon as you introduce a decimal point (whether it be a Point or a PointF) it throws it's toys out of the pram and returns bizarre results.

So I suppose the question is how would I modify the above to get it do what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try (P1.X*percentage + P2.X*(100 - percentage))/100

Comment: That's the ticket, many thanks.

Comment: @user1006221 That's not correct.  Just try it on a few sample values and you'll see it's not right.

Comment: I just wrote a loop to test it at 5% increments, it works fine.

Comment: The exact formula of the linear interpolation is well explained here : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918779

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong formula.

The weighted middle between two points is `p1 + (p2-p1) * percentage`, which just happens to work out for 0.5 as `p1 + (p2-p1)*0.5 = (p1 + p2) * 0.5`

Comment: is that `(p1 + (p2 - p1)) * percentage` or `p1 + ((p2 - p1) * percentage)`?

Comment: It should be the second one. Start at p1 and add some percentage of the difference. If you added 100% of the difference then you would be at p2.

Answer (score 0):

Incase the above answer was not clear enough:

```
travel(from, to, percentDistance) =
    totalDistance = to - from
    from + (totalDistance * percentDistance)
```